# Class hierarchy/dependency diagram generator for C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, class

Is there some tool to generate class hierarchy/dependency diagrams by inspecting C++ code in Linux?

I have this big collection of C++ files given to me and such a tool would be invaluable to help me 
understand the source code. I am getting a little tangled up in understanding it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). It may also be shipped with your distribution.

You may need [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate the graphs. There is [a simple example](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) and [output](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/diagrams/html/inherits.html).

And this is a more complicated example from the legend file generated by doxygen:

Code (NOTE: if you only want to generate the graphs, the comments are not required.):

```
/*! Invisible class because of truncation */
class Invisible { };

/*! Truncated class, inheritance relation is hidden */
class Truncated : public Invisible { };

/* Class not documented with doxygen comments */
class Undocumented { };

/*! Class that is inherited using public inheritance */
class PublicBase : public Truncated { };

/*! A template class */
template<class T> class Templ { };

/*! Class that is inherited using protected inheritance */
class ProtectedBase { };

/*! Class that is inherited using private inheritance */
class PrivateBase { };

/*! Class that is used by the Inherited class */
class Used { };

/*! Super class that inherits a number of other classes */
class Inherited : public PublicBase,
                  protected ProtectedBase,
                  private PrivateBase,
                  public Undocumented,
                  public Templ<int>
{
  private:
    Used *m_usedClass;
};
```

Result:

[image]

You **do not** need to comment your code to generate these graphs. The first example has no comments at all. The second example has one class without doxygen style comment. Just set the appropriate parameter (at least `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` should be set. I cannot recall whether this is all that is needed).

Comment: Doesn't doxygen require you to comment in a specific format so that it can later generate anything at all? I think what the OP asks for is a tool which can draw class hierarchy diagram by analysing code

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Comments are not required for DoxyGen to work. It can even be used on a project with no comment at all. You just need to set appropriate parameters.

Comment: @fefe: _It can even be used on a project with no comment at all._ Heh, I thought it was _mostly_ used on projects with no comments at all, so lazy developers could say: look, we have documentation for our code!

Comment: @fefe Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. The system lookss really powerful. As a side note, for others looking at this thread, I found a GUI frontend for doxygen named **doxywizard** which is really easy to work with. It is available from the Ubuntu repository for download.

Comment: Doesn't generate the dependencies of the class, only what classes it inherited from. On the page to the example you posted, there is class B that depends on class A but the output image doesn't show it, it only shows inheritence.

Answer (score 7):

There's a promising new tool called [`cpp-depenencies`](https://github.com/tomtom-international/cpp-dependencies).

It can generate `component` dependency diagrams (like below) as well as `class` hierarchy diagrams (by passing an option to treat each source file as a component).

[image]

There's also [`cpp_dependency_graph`](https://github.com/shreyasbharath/cpp_dependency_graph), which is able to generate component/include dependency graphs in `dot`, `d3.js` or JSON formats.

Below is an example `d3.js` visualisation.

[image]

Disclaimer - I am the author of `cpp_dependency_graph`.

Comment: cpp_dependency is a crap. It can even not parse a single cpp file alone in a folder. Why are you proposing a dependency tool when the author asks for a inheritance diagram too ? Your tool cannot build 0.1% of what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eclipse as IDE, you can use type hierarchy to see class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

If you use kdevelop, you could install [kdevcontrolflowgraphview plugin](http://liveblue.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/visualize-your-code-in-kdevelop/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you guys to try out Source Navigator
An IDE for C/C++/Fortran/Java/Tcl/PHP/Python

Win: https://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/

Linux (& mac?):
http://chenweixiang.github.io/2019/09/09/source-navigator-ng.html#install-source-navigator-ng-4-5-on-linuxmint

Its somewhat outdated, bit has been a long time useful tool.
Has not been updated for a while (~2014), so It'll be confused from the newer c++14(+) features. Presumably also some from C++11.
But to display rather complicated class hierarchy, include dependencies investigation and for rough code navigation, its sufficient (provided that it won't crash on some complicated code constructs).

Worthy to note, there used to be Source Navigator Extensions - basically same thing, but you could dispatch several independent windows.

Here is source code:
https://github.com/rogerz/sourcenavigator

Answer (score -1):

[Source Trail](https://www.sourcetrail.com/) is an easy-to-use tool in my experience with an intuitive GUI that helps you explore the relationship between a language element and others that are related to it. It worked very well for me on MacOS.
As of September 2021, it is no longer developed, but the repository remains available.